# Этимология слова "дрыхнуть"

Tags: этимология

"Дрыхнуть" — разговорно-пренебрежительный синоним слова "спать". А откуда это слово взялось, какова его этимология?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

По сведениям этимологического словаря, слово дрыхнуть - исконно русское. Образовано от   от утраченного дрых, образованного (суф. -х, ср. смех) от той же основы (с перегласовкой ы/е), что и дремать.